# UWP updating current window from background

Tags: xaml, view, uwp, winrt-xaml, updating

I am porting an App from WinRT to UWP. (I have already ported it to iOS and Android)

My App has multiple pages. I need to be able to determine which page is currently viewed, and then update the contents. (For various reasons, DataBinding is not an option.)

I have a routine that runs in the background (not on the UI thread), getting called from the dispatch timer.

In WinRT, I handled it as follows:

```
            // If current window is MainPage, then update the displayed fields 
        var _Frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        Page _Page = _Frame.Content as Page;
        if (_Page is MainPage)
        {
            MainPage _XPage = _Frame.Content as MainPage;
            _XPage.SetFieldsTick(spoton);
        }
```

Since UWP return null for Windows.Current.Content, I set flags in the Navigation routine to keep track of the current view. I'd like to fix this kludge correctly.

The next step is how to actually change the fields.

I have a routine in the XAML code behind that sets the fields

```
        public void SetFieldsTick(bool spot)
    {
        UTC_Data.Text = Vars.DateStrZ;
    }
```

If I want to reference this from my background routine, then the routine must be static. If I make this change, then the routine can't reference the fields on the page since they are not static.

I know that it is probably something obvious, but I am stumped.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you get the current page in your background routine successfully? In addtion, you mentioned you want to call the SetFieldsTick method in the background routine, when you get the MainPage instance in the routine, you can directly call the _XPage.SetFieldsTick, why you must make the SetFieldsTick method static? Can you show more details about these?

Comment: When I run the program, the line "var _Frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;" throws an exception: "Window.Current.Content = 'Window.Current.Content' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'"

Comment: SetFieldsTick is called when the page loads and works just fine, when called from within the class. In the background routine, since _XPage isn't initialized, I call it as "Home_Page.SetFieldsTick(true);" and I get the compile error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property.." If I make the routine static, I get the same compile error, but this time with each field reference in the page.

Comment: I tried adding a timer to Home_Page, but when it tries to call SetFieldsTick, I get a message "UTC_Data.Text = 'UTC_Data.Text' threw an exception of type 'System.Exception'" (UTC_Data is the first field that I am trying to update) So, how do I update the current view from background without using databinding?

Comment: When I tried to test, I didn't receive these exceptions. Can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test? It will be more helpful.

Comment: Create a paged App using the directions from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/layout/page-layout . 
Add a text field to one page. 
Create a dispatch timer in App.xaml.cs that runs each second.         
public void StartTimer()
        {
            DateTime startTime;
            startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            var dispatcherTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(DispatcherTimer_Tick, startTime, 0, 1000);
        } 
Have that dispatch timer attempt to change the text field to the current time.

Answer (score 0):

The [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=netframework-4.8) you used will provide a mechanism for executing a method on a thread pool thread at specified intervals. It run on a separate thread. So if you want to handle the the app's UI, it needs to run on the UI's dispatcher thread. In that case, you can use [Dispatcher.RunAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher.runasync?view=winrt-18362) method to callback on the UI thread. For example:

App.xaml.cs:

```
public void StartTimer() 
{ 
    DateTime startTime; 
    startTime = DateTime.UtcNow; 
    var dispatcherTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(DispatcherTimer_Tick, startTime, 0, 1000); 
}

private async void DispatcherTimer_Tick(object state)
{
    await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        var _Frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        Page _Page = _Frame.Content as Page;
        if (_Page is MainPage)
        {
            MainPage _XPage = _Frame.Content as MainPage;
            _XPage.SetFieldsTick(true);
        }
    });
}
```

In addition, it is recommended to use [DispatcherTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer?view=winrt-18362) which can be used to run code on the same thread that produces the UI thread. In that case, you don't need to callback on the UI thread.

```
public void StartTimer() 
{ 
    var dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
    dispatcherTimer.Start();
}

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    var _Frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    Page _Page = _Frame.Content as Page;
    if (_Page is MainPage)
    {
        MainPage _XPage = _Frame.Content as MainPage;
        _XPage.SetFieldsTick(true);
    }
}
```